Wrong definition of in/out states in non-perturbative derivation of LSZ formula?
There are different derivations of LSZ formula. By non-perturbative I mean that such derivation of LSZ can apply to asymptotic states like bound states that doesn't have associated fields in the Lagrangian.
Such derivation of LSZ can be found in Peskin, Coleman or Srednicki. They are a bit different, but they both muddle through what is meant by an in/out state.
"In state" should be a Heisenberg-picture state  $|\psi_{in}\rangle_{H}$ defined at t=0, which put in Schrodinger picture looks like two spatially separated wave packets of single particle states in the interacting theory, as $t
\rightarrow -\infty$, that is
$|\psi_{in}\rangle_{S}(t=-\infty)=|two\ separated\ wavepacktes\ of\ single\ particle\ states\rangle$
and $|\psi_{in}\rangle_{H}=|\psi_{in}\rangle_{S}(t=0)$
at t=0 the wavepackets collide and it is a very complicated state that has overlap with all kinds of states in the Hilbert space.
However,  one can check that in derivation of LSZ, all three textbooks actaully muddled through by taking $|\psi_{in}\rangle_{H}=|\psi_{in}\rangle_{S}(t=-\infty)$, in one way or another.
At least this identification looks wrong to me and it is not obvious how this "wrong formula" can somehow produce the correct result.
Any comment or insight is appreciated.

Which pages? Which eqs?

@Qmechanic Peskin, p226 ,     Coleman p293 eq14.12 eq14.13 ,   Srednicki p36 eq5.8, eq5.9. Actually, the  problem is not manifest in any specific equations or pages, one can conclude that they all "secretly" used this wrong identification by following the full argument. In particular, Coleman and Peskin contradicted their own definition of in/out states.
